# Домашняя сеть: неверный роутинг

Tags: сеть

Добрый день.
Дома есть простенькая сеть: интернет-кабель заходит в проводной роутер ([TP-Link TL-R460](http://www.tp-linkru.com/products/details/?model=TL-R460)), роутер раздает по кабелю на пару устройств плюс wi-fi роутер ([ASUS RT-N13U](http://www.asus.com/ru/Networking/RTN13U/)), работающий в режиме AP. Все прекрасно, интернет летает в меру своих способностей, сеть висит на стандартных 192.168.0.1/24, `arp -a` показывает верные адреса, но при попытке протрейсроутить соседний хост пакеты уходят куда-то не туда: все, что я вижу в выводе - это хосты из трех звездочек, судя по всему, пакеты почему-то уходят через провайдера в глобальную сеть или циклятся внутри сети. Отсюда вопросы:

- Как разобраться, куда и почему уходят пакеты?
- Как заставить вышеприведенный роутер (tp-link) по-человечески отображаться при traceroute-запросе?

Comment: Я бы для начала проверил маршруты на конечных устройствах и на роутере. Например с помощью команды route. Обратите внимание на метрику. Если используется какой-либо туннель (например VPN), то пакеты могут уходить в него.

Comment: icmp не правильно работает где-то в роутере, насчет роутера не уверен, может перешить его в openwrt/ddwrt ? в половине tplink были какие-то проблемы с безопасностью на вендорских прошивках. попробуйте кстати tcptraceroute

пакеты скорее всего дропаются роутером  и никуда не уходят, попробуйте на соседнем хосте wireshark запустить, чтобы понять приходит ему чего нить или нет. домой ethernet заходит ? подключите в разрыв между роутером и интернетом комп в режиме бриджа - проверьте какие пакеты инуд с роутера ( ну или просто комп вместо входящего линка подключите)

Comment: мое предсказание - роутер фильтрует [icmp type 11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol#Time_exceeded)

погодите, они все в одной ethernet сети ? так поди сами устройства фильтруют icmp

Comment: @mayar, туннелей нет, [вывод route](http://pastebin.com/hq7iMhYe) для ноута и wi-fi раздатчика (на главный роутер не смог зайти)

@eicto, боюсь, тут не только icmp, я не могу ни пропинговать, ни подключиться к нужному хосту. tcptraceroute нашел ya.ru (обычный не смог) и кинул !H от хоста .110 при поиске .114. Перепрошивать бы сейчас не хотелось, хотя в принципе возможно.

upd

> подключите в разрыв 

Да у меня дай боже пять сантиметров криво обжатого провода здесь торчат. Тут надо все менять и читать наконец книги по сети, но сейчас цель просто нормально настроить внутренний коннект.

Comment: ну wireshark проверяйте, обычно диагностика сети начинается с wireshark/tcpdump на всех устройствах, где возможно.

а у вас интерфейс локалки  и  интерфейс на котором точка доступа в бридже ?

Comment: а откуда взялась мысль, что traceroute в локальной сети должен через роутер идти? в одной подесети маршрут прямой будет с одним hop'ом.  
Если не брать экзотических случаев дублирования ip'шников, то скорее всего пинг просто запрещен на конечных устройствах фаерволами.

Comment: @eicto, я туплю в вопросах сетей страшно, но бриджей нигде не делал. У меня просто воткнута wi-fi точка в роутер, роутер заведует dhcp, на ноуте, с которого тестил, все коннектится через wlan0.

Comment: ну они по идее по умолчанию в бридже, в общем как я сказал - сниффер ваш друг.